# Restrict guest users to buy a specific product multiple times in the same week based on previous orders and phone number in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

I'm looking for a restriction if a guest user has bought a specific product 2 times in a week he must not be able to make another purchase of same product.

Im looking to apply this restriction based on guest user's **phone number**.

I've seen many posts related to that but all focus on registered users however i want to apply this restriction for guest users.

Based on [Limit customers to buy a particular product multiple times in the same week based on previous orders in WooCommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65108234/11987538) answer code this is the code I am currently using, unfortunately without the desired result (this snippet keeps restricting user even if the number is totally new and different).

```php
function action_woocommerce_checkout_process() {
    // Only for guests
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return;
    
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
        // NOT empty
        if ( ! empty ( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
            $customer_phone = $_POST['billing_phone'];  
        }
    }
    // Phone NOT empty
    if ( ! empty ( $customer_phone ) ) {        
        // Time in seconds (1 week)
        $time_in_seconds = 604800;
        
        // Set limit per week
        $limit = 2;
        
        // Specific product id
        $specific_product_name = 'Buy product' ;
        
        // Get orders from last week from customer by email
        $orders_last_week_by_customer_phone = wc_get_orders( array(
            'date_created' => '>' . (time() - $time_in_seconds ),
            'customer-phone' => $customer_phone,
        ));
        
        // Total (counter)
        $total = 0;
        
        // Iterating through each order
        foreach ( $orders_last_week_by_customer_phone as $order ) {
            // Going through order items
            foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
                // Get product ID
                $product_name = $item->get_name();
                
                // Compare
                if ( $specific_product_name == $product_name ) {
                    // Get quantity
                    $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
                    
                    // Add to total
                    $total += $quantity;
                }
            }
        }
        

        // Show error when total >= limit
        if ( $total >= $limit ) {
           wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'You are not allowed to buy more than %d products. For more information please contact support. phone', 'woocommerce' ), $limit), 'error' );
        }       
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_process', 10, 0 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`customer-phone` simply does not exist, you should use `billing_phone` instead.

See: [wc_get_orders and WC_Order_Query](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query)

**Address and Name**

billing_first_name, billing_last_name, billing_company, billing_address_1, billing_address_2, billing_city, billing_state, billing_postcode, billing_country, billing_email, billing_phone, shipping_first_name, shipping_last_name, shipping_company, shipping_address_1, shipping_address_2, shipping_city, shipping_state, shipping_postcode, shipping_country, customer_ip_address

---

**Customer**

Accepts a string or an integer: The order's billing email or customer id.

---

---

**Note:** If it is purely about the number of times the product appears in an order (1x per order) versus the quantity of a product per order, there is no need to use `get_quantity()` in the `foreach` loop.

---

So you get:

```php
function action_woocommerce_checkout_process() {
    // Only for guests
    if ( is_user_logged_in() ) return;
    
    // Isset
    if ( isset( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
        // NOT empty
        if ( ! empty ( $_POST['billing_phone'] ) ) {
            $customer_phone = $_POST['billing_phone'];  
        }
    }
    
    // Isset
    if ( isset ( $customer_phone ) ) {      
        // Time in seconds (1 week)
        $time_in_seconds = 604800;
        
        // Set limit per week
        $limit = 2;
        
        // Specific product name
        $specific_product_name = 'Buy product';
        
        // Get orders from last week from customer by phone
        $orders_last_week_by_customer_phone = wc_get_orders( array(
            'date_created' => '>' . (time() - $time_in_seconds ),
            'billing_phone' => $customer_phone,
        ));
        
        // Total (counter)
        $total = 0;
        
        // Iterating through each order
        foreach ( $orders_last_week_by_customer_phone as $order ) {
            // Going through order items
            foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
                // Name of the product
                $product_name = $item->get_name();
                
                // Compare
                if ( $specific_product_name == $product_name ) {                                            
                    // Add to total
                    $total += 1;
                }
            }
        }

        // Show error when total >= limit
        if ( $total >= $limit ) {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( __( 'You are not allowed to buy more than %d products. For more information please contact support.', 'woocommerce' ), $limit ), 'error' );
        }   
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_process', 'action_woocommerce_checkout_process', 10, 0 );
```